goaccess fails to parse my nginx access log format
This the ngnix access log format I have:
log_format info
'[$time_local] '
'client:"$remote_addr" '
'host:"$host" '
'user:"$remote_user" '
'server_block:"$server_name:$server_port" '
'request:"$request" '
'requestid:"$http_requestid" '
'cache_status:"$upstream_cache_status" '
'rsp_status:"$status($upstream_status)" '
'body_bytes_sent:"$body_bytes_sent" '
'time_taken:"$request_time($upstream_response_time)" '
'up_connect_time:"$upstream_connect_time"';
Eg: log content
[09/Sep/2024:00:04:44 -0400] conn_stats:"299814 : 1" client:"10.88.0.1" host_to_upstream:"mybox.com->192.168.1.103:8553" user:"-" server_block:"mybox.com:443" request:"GET /dds/v1/keys/fake/something HTTP/1.1" requestid:"-" server_cache_bypass:"-" cookie:"-" user_agent:"lua-resty-http/0.12.4 (Lua) ngx_lua/10026" referer:"-" cache_status:"-" rsp_status:"200(200)" body_bytes_sent:"451" time_taken:"0.002(0.002)" up_connect_time:"0.001" up_header_time:"0.002" up_bytes_sent:"231" up_bytes_rcvd:"975" 
[09/Sep/2024:00:09:39 -0400] conn_stats:"300753 : 1" client:"10.88.0.1" host_to_upstream:"mybox.com->192.168.1.103:8553" user:"-" server_block:"mybox.com:443" request:"GET /dds/v1/keys/fake/something HTTP/1.1" requestid:"-" server_cache_bypass:"-" cookie:"-" user_agent:"lua-resty-http/0.12.4 (Lua) ngx_lua/10026" referer:"-" cache_status:"-" rsp_status:"200(200)" body_bytes_sent:"451" time_taken:"0.004(0.004)" up_connect_time:"0.001" up_header_time:"0.004" up_bytes_sent:"231" up_bytes_rcvd:"975"

I have tried
goaccess access.log --log-format='[%d:%t %^] conn_stats:"%^" client:"%^" host_to_upstream:"%^" user:"%^" server_block:"%^:%^" request:"%^" requestid:"%^" server_cache_bypass:"%^" cookie:"%^" referer:"%^" cache_status:"%^" rsp_status:"%^(%^)" body_bytes_sent:"%^" time_taken:"%^(%^)" up_connect_time:"%^" up_header_time:"%^" up_bytes_sent:"%^" up_bytes_rcvd:"%^"' --date-format='%d/%b/%Y' --time-format='%T' 

==64998== GoAccess - version 1.9.3 - Jun  1 2024 00:37:37
==64998== Config file: /usr/local/Cellar/goaccess/1.9.3/etc/goaccess/goaccess.conf
==64998== https://goaccess.io - <hello@goaccess.io>
==64998== Released under the MIT License.
==64998==
==64998== FILE: access.log
==64998== Parsed 2 lines producing the following errors:
==64998==
==64998== IPv4/6 is required.
==64998== IPv4/6 is required.
==64998==
==64998== Format Errors - Verify your log/date/time format

Tried multiple changes in the date and timeformat, but didn't help,
Not sure how to overcome with this?
